# Nginx: serving wordpress core and wp-content folders separately

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Im having trouble serving my Wordpress site with a `wp-content` folder outside the wordpress installation.

```
--- /var/www
  |
  |
  -- /var/www/wordpress
  |
  |
  -- /var/www/wp-content
```

Here is my Nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;

    # buffering
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    # Gzip compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_comp_level     6;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_min_length     1000;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;

    # logging
    rewrite_log on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    # mime types
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    index index.php;

    # server
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /var/www;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location / {
            try_files /wordpress/$uri /wordpress/$uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }               

        location /wp-content {
            try_files /wp-content/$uri /wp-content/$uri/ /wp-content/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }             

        location ~ \.php$ {
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            fastcgi_keep_conn on;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }
    }
}
```

This is "kind of" working although some things such as fonts and css are not loading.

Comment: I suggest to run the debug ( https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html ) log and see what file request is done, assumption is this `/wp-content//wp-content/....css`. Try to use only `try_files $uri /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args` . I suggest to read the excellent doc how nginx handles a request https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: On the other hand you can create a symlink named wp-content to ../wp-content . And set the root to /var/www/wordpress/. Fast and dirty.